# Convert VARCHAR in format YYMMDD to YYYYMMDD and ignore invalid date formats

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, stored-procedures

I have a table with a VARCHAR field called ArrivalDate in format yymmdd (such as 170202).
I am writing a query which converts it to yyyymmdd so it should become 20170202.

However my problem is that I need to cater for the case when inappropriate data is entered into the field, and my query needs to exclude that data. I am achieving this exclusion by using the ISDATE function of TSQL. I also need to select the least recent entry (I'm using order by asc for this).

I am using a variety of converts to write this query, below is my implementation with a sample table and data.

```
Declare @tmp TABLE (theDates VARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO @tmp VALUES('170202')

SELECT TOP 1 t.theDates
WHEN (ISDATE(t.theDates) = 1) THEN CONVERT( VARCHAR(max),CONVERT(datetime t.theDates), 112)
FROM @tmp t
WHERE (ISDATE(t.theDates) = 1)
ORDER BY CAST(t.theDates as DATE)
```

However I do not like my approach and it occasionally fails conversion and throws an error with values such as 02/02/02 which breaks the query. Can someone please show me a better way of writing this functionality.

Much appreciated!

Comment: Why would you ever store a date NOT as a date?

Comment: Using SQL Server 2012 and above, [TRY_CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx) is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: This is just the table am working with @ErikPhilips. I did not write the schema, I would never store dates as a VARCHAR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [TRY_CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(TRY_CONVERT_TSQL);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLRESULTS.F1);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLQUERY.F1);k(MISCELLANEOUSFILESPROJECT);k(DevLang-TSQL)&rd=true) and [CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(CAST_TSQL);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLRESULTS.F1);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLQUERY.F1);k(MISCELLANEOUSFILESPROJECT);k(DevLang-TSQL)&rd=true) to get the correct format and convert the value. Then check that the string is exactly 6 character to prevent other formats from being returned.

```
SELECT
  convert(char(10),convert(date, theDates, 12),112)
FROM
  (values('02/02/02'),('170202')) x(theDates)
WHERE
  try_convert(date, theDates, 12) is not null
  and len(theDates) = 6
```

Comment: Your solution worked best. Thank you very much.

Thank you to everyone else too

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cast(@date as datetime)`

```
declare @date varchar(max);
    set @date='170202';
    select
    CASE WHEN (ISDATE(cast(@date as datetime)) = 1) 
        THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(max), CONVERT(datetime,  cast(@date as datetime)), 112) end
        from table

    set @date='02/02/02';
    select
    CASE WHEN (ISDATE(cast(@date as datetime)) = 1) 
        THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(max), CONVERT(datetime,  cast(@date as datetime)), 112) end
        from table
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However if I insert the same values, one with clash format, one without (02/12/02 and 021202 into the table and run your query the results are different

Comment: The 021202 comes out as   20021202 
The 02/12/02 comes out as 20020212

It looks like the mm and dd have swapped around depending on whether the slashes are in the date. Any ideas how to get around this?

Comment: @Mark some of the other answers handle that

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Thank you for your answer, I voted it best answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

please use create function for check dateformat is Valid or not and use this fun in your query inside cash clouse.

```html
ALTER  FUNCTION dbo.f_CheckDate
(@InDate nvarchar(25))
RETURNS DATE
AS
    BEGIN
        declare @Return DATETIME
        select @return = CASE WHEN ISDATE(@InDate) = 1
                             THEN   @InDate
                            ELSE NULL
                            END
        return @return
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [TRY_CAST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh974669.aspx) or [TRY_CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx) if value cannot be cast it will return NULL.

```
SELECT 
  TRY_CAST('20170228' AS DATETIME),
  TRY_CAST('170228' AS DATETIME),
  TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME, '20170228'),
  TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME, '170228')
```

This works for SQL Server 2012 and newer.